# Problem with at sign in div name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which has some divs. Each div id starts with the word divfor and have a suffix after that. Like divforjohn, divforjim ... etc. These suffixes come from database.

My problem is when i try to load something in that div it creates problem if it have the @ sign in it. So, if I do something like below:

```
 $("#divfor"+divsuffix).html('some text goes here.');
```

then it doesnot make any problem if the divname is `divforjohn` but doesnot work if the divname is `divforjohn@x`.

So, how can I address a div that has @sign in its id? or its a limitation/bug of jquery?

Thx.

Comment: According to http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class you can use any character, as long as it's not a space…

Comment: But this is for html5 which is not fully supported in browsers yet

Comment: @Aly: This is just standardizing what browsers already support. You don’t need to worry about browser support — this already works everywhere. Read the article.

Answer (score 3):

To target the element with `id="divforjohn@x"` in JavaScript (be it through `document.querySelectorAll` or through jQuery/Sizzle) you’ll need to escape the `@`, like this:

```
$('#divforjohn\\@x')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/nafmt/

Also, the accepted answer is wrong — it states the ID naming rules that were included in the HTML 4 spec. The thing is, **browsers never implemented this**, so in HTML5 these rules aren’t as restrictive anymore. See [“The `id` attribute just got more `class`y in HTML5”](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class).

It’s perfectly safe to use weird characters in values for `id` or `class` attributes as long as you know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
As mentioned in the comment, at a point when your only aim is to support HTML5 browsers, by all mean use anything unique and contain at least 1 character for your ID attributes.

[See this Stackoverflow thread for further discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

---

Hi, I hope **this part of the document is helpful** for you:

[6 Basic HTML data types - IDs and Names](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

This is not a bug of jquery/javascript etc.

You can check the **more formal HTML4 RFC** of course.

Is there any reason you must have **@ inside the id of an element**?

I suggest you should try to avoid it because some legacy browsers aimed to support html4 might not have implemented it this way, as

Comment: “I suggest you should try to avoid it because some browsers/future browsers might mis-interpret the @, without invalidating the HTML RFCs.” This has never been a problem in any browser, and it won’t be in the future either. The HTML spec (“HTML5”) allows any character in the value of `ID` attributes. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456164/problem-with-at-sign-in-div-name/5457584#5457584

Answer (score 1):

actually your ID can not contain @ as @Peter describes, once u changed your id then u can use like this

There is regex selector for jQuery:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

That is used like this:

```
 $(':regex(id,/^divfor.*/)');
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works :

```
var d = document.getElementById("divforjohn@x");
$(d).html('some text goes here.');
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/T6HA3/)

Comment: doesnt seem to work if you use the $('#divforjohn@x') instead of document.getElementById, but +1 for showing this

Comment: I know I doesn't work with $('#divforjohn@x'), my solution is just a workaround. Thanks for the +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be doing similar [to this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/at-sign).  I would suggest just base 64'n the string before putting it in the div, then using the base64 name for everything.  Or a row id, something generic, that you can always predict the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the ID naming rules:

- Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
- Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z),
  digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"),
  underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and
  periods (".")
- Values are case-sensitive

Comment: Thanks. I should know it before!

Comment: Please, don't link to w3schools. ever. again. (try w3fools.com instead)

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is incorrect. These ID naming rules were never enforced by browsers and are much less restrictive in HTML5. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456164/problem-with-at-sign-in-div-name/5457584#5457584 P.S. http://w3fools.com/